# Lightbox 2 - Embeded Media Field / Media : Youtube can't play videos on LightBox2

Tags: nodes, media, javascript, files

I tried using both 'Embed media field' and 'Media : Youtube' module in D& website to create a content-type field to embed youtube videos and play in on lightbox2. Although images work well with the lightbox, there is some problem with videos.I enabling the videos settings under configuration/User interface/Lightbox2 but is of no use.

All i want is to play youtube videos in the lightbox

Comment: I think its better u write a custom jQuery code to play  the video. Makes sense and will reduce the time by a huge margin. If u need i am ready to share my piece of code.

Comment: I really appreciate your helping hand. Humbly i request to share your code with all of us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something I have done in the past is create a content for my video and use your embedded media stuff you already have.

I then change the Manage display to not show the video on the full content view.

I then use a module like [Colorbox Node](http://drupal.org/project/colorbox_node) to render just the video in a colorbox window.  You do this be editing the Colorbox display to only show the video.

So your full node page content has everything but the rendered video.  You add a link that points to the current node page as a colorbox node link.  When the user clicks on that link it will show the video.

So you are essentially switch the display based on how the node is rendered.  Either through a full page or through a colorbox modal.  Saves on code duplication :) and keeps it compact.

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

You can install [Embedded Media Field](http://drupal.org/project/emfield)  module and [Video Embed Field](http://drupal.org/project/video_embed_field) module.

Then add a cck field of type "Video Embed" and widget "Video" for a content type.

In that field you can enter the youtube video url. Then display that node in lightbox and it will work fine to play in the lightbox.