# Clickable preview of a youtube video in a Lightbox?

Tags: views, media, javascript, files

So I have been trying for a month now to get a nice gallery view working. It's a view displaying items of a custom "Gallery element" content type, that can contain either an image or a youtube video.

I want to have my gallery displayed as a 4x3 grid of thumbnails, that you can click on and get a lightbox output of the media file, wether it is an image or a video.

I managed to get the images working using the Lightbox2 module, but somehow the youtube videos need a little bit more working... So far I haven't managed to even see these videos in a lightbox. Either only an unclickable thumbnail appears in the gallery, or the full sized video if I remove the "Youtube Preview Image" display from the **manage file display** panel of **File types** in the configuration.

I do have checked the "Enable video support" checkbox in the Lightbox2 configuration, yet I cannot seem to find a way to display a video in those! One thing I wonder, is [why don't I get the same field format "Lightbox2" options as for images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jf95.jpg)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well! Thanks to [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/37474/14751), I just found a workaround. I had to install the [Video Embed Field](http://drupal.org/project/video_embed_field) module, and now I can display YouTube videos in a Colorbox popup window perfeclty fine. And Colorbox only, because Lightbox2 is still not supported by Video Embed Field.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with these modules (for Druplal 7)

- Media
- Media Video Embed
- Colorbox
- Embedded Media Field
- Media Colorbox

Maybe some more, such as requirements, but with those modules you can get the job done. You must install all of these module. The colorbox module needs the jquery.colorbox-min.js plugin.

What you do is this:

enable "colorbox load" of the colorbox config

create a new field for your content-type with an "embedded video" field

in the display setting for the field, choose "thumbnail with colorbox" of something to that effect

if it's not working then your missing a module or js plugin, or something is ill-configed, or you need to wait for the Media Internet field to fetch the thumbnail